# HTML5 canvas rectangles using easeljs

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs

I am creating a multiple choice quiz on a canvas.
Naturally for the options I used squares as checkBoxes. Now I have put an event Listener on clicking a checkbox, it should get colored. However the listener doesnt work on entire square only the border. May I know how can the problem be resolved and also I wanted to know how to know if a square is filled with a color.

Function for loading options with oIndex from 0,1, till numberOfOptions
pHeight is a a global variable, optionChecks- the checkbox and optionsClick- the invisible rectangle for clicking on

```
 function loadOption(oIndex){

 optionChecks[oIndex] = new createjs.Shape();
 optionChecks[oIndex].graphics.beginStroke("blue");
 optionChecks[oIndex].graphics.setStrokeStyle(2);
 optionChecks[oIndex].graphics.drawRect( canvas2.width*0.05 ,pHeight+20 ,20 ,20);
 stage.addChild(optionChecks[oIndex] );
 stage.update();

 var y1 = pHeight+15;
 var ht = y1;
 var maxWidth = canvas2.width *0.8;
 var text = problemOptions[oIndex];
   var lineHeight = 25;
   var x = (canvas2.width - maxWidth) / 2;
   var y = y1;//pHeight+15;
 //function for wrapping text  
  wrapText(ctx2, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight);
  ht = wHeight +10;
  stage.update();

 optionClicks[oIndex] = new createjs.Shape();
 optionClicks[oIndex].graphics.beginStroke("black");
 optionClicks[oIndex].graphics.setStrokeStyle(2);
 optionClicks[oIndex].graphics.drawRect( canvas2.width*0.05,y1,maxWidth-500 ,pHeight-y1+10);
 optionClicks[oIndex].addEventListener("click", handleOption); 
 stage.addChild(optionClicks[oIndex] );
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw another opaque rect and use the button's `hitArea` - http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_hitArea